# How do I reopen a question that was incorrectly reported as off-topic?

Tags: support, specific-question, reopen

A few days ago, I asked a question related to the addition of magnetic flux densities when there are multiple magnets in a specific piece of equipment. For some reason, it was considered off-topic, even though it is about the physics involved and has nothing to do with engineering. How do I report this?

Link for question: [How can you find the average magnetic flux density of multiple magnets near each other?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/595254/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whittled down your question amount to two things :

> I want to know the average magnetic flux density on the surface of the track. Can anyone help me with this?

This would normally be considered a homework-type question.  At a minimum you would be expected to show your own effort to work out the theoretical model.  Even then we generally only answer this category of questions if they have a conceptual issue.

If you make appropriate edits to show this your question will automatically be placed on the list of questions to be voted for reopening.  If enough people vote to reopen it, then it will be reopened.  Note that if you repost the question it would most likely be closed as a duplicate of the original.

There is (AFAIK) no other way for you to force the question to be reopened.

> Any other tips or help with this topic is also appreciated.

This just is not a type of question we deal with.  It is vague and there is no way to define a correct answer, something we generally want to be possible for questions on SE.

Regarding it being closed as "engineering", this could be argued to be a valid interpretation of your question.  You are building something, you want help with some aspect of that - that is engineering.

Comment: The reopen process has already begun on the question. With this meta post bringing attention to the main question, it is likely the question will be reopened just by users who disagree with the closure / do not understand the closure reason.

Comment: @BioPhysicist ...only to be closed as a homework question.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I now get that it was too vague to properly answer, but the problem was that I did not know if an answer did exist. But, I still deleted the question, so it is no longer a problem.